# In Swift 3, How to change the resolution on the selected image in Pickerview Controller

Tags: swift, swift3, core-image, cgsize

The resolution of the original image selected in imagePickerControllerd is 2448x3264.

I want to keep the ratio and change the resolution.

I need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]!) {
    dPrint("IMAGE DICT>> \(editingInfo)")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    var cropImage : UIImage?

    if image.size.width > 300 || image.size.height > 300
    {
        cropImage = self.imageWithImage(image: image, scaledToSize: CGSize(width: 300.0, height: 300.0))
    }
    else{
        cropImage = image
    }

  let lowResolutionImg =  cropImage?.lowestQualityJPEGNSData as Data!
}
func imageWithImage(image:UIImage ,scaledToSize newSize:CGSize)-> UIImage
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize )
        image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
        let newImage : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!;
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return newImage
    }
//MARK:- EXTENSION FOR UIIMAGE
extension UIImage {
    var uncompressedPNGData: Data      { return UIImagePNGRepresentation(self)!        }
    var highestQualityJPEGNSData: Data { return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 1.0)!  }
    var highQualityJPEGNSData: Data    { return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 0.75)! }
    var mediumQualityJPEGNSData: Data  { return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 0.5)!  }
    var lowQualityJPEGNSData: Data     { return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 0.25)! }
    var lowestQualityJPEGNSData:Data   { return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 0.0)!  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, however, the aspect ratio of original photos has changed. What should I do if I try to fit the size on the height?

Comment: In the storyboard set `UIImageView` display property `Aspect Fit`

Comment: Still not working...  your code is "scaledToSize: CGSize(width: 300.0, height: 300.0))" . But I want aspect ratio as width. What should I do?

Comment: if you want to compress image then above code is perfect and if you want to aspect ratio this is different topic which don't understand what you exactly want, because aspect ration is same as same height and width

Comment: If above code is working for you brother you can give a thumbs up:)